# Bootstrap and Microdata markup for breadcrumb? Issue—extra spaces

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, metadata, markup, breadcrumbs, microdata

This is what Twitter Bootstrap's markup for breadcrumb looks like:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
    <li class="active">Data</li>
</ol>
```

Combining Twitter Bootstrap and Microdata markup to make breadcrumbs search engine friendly:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
        <a href="#" itemprop="url">
            <span itemprop="title">Home</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
        <a href="#" itemprop="url">
            <span itemprop="title">Library</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
        <a href="#" itemprop="url">
            <span itemprop="title">Data</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

The problem is, if the latter markup is used, I noticed that an extra space is being added before each link in the breadcrumb, as shown in the screenshot below. The same doesn't happen with the original markup.

[image: Screenshot]

**[Here's the related JS Fiddle for the same](http://jsfiddle.net/73Ps7/2/).**

It's not a big deal, but I'd like to know the underlying reason, which I was unable to identify.

**PS:** Both markups add a space before each link in the breadcrumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These spaces are created by line breaks in the HTML.

Related questions:

- [About the space and line-break in HTML source code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4714619/1591669)
- [Why does the browser renders a newline as space?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588356/1591669)

Answer (score 1):

The child Attribute needs to be included in second and subsequent list items, per the description of breadcrumbs at [Data-Vocabulary.org](http://www.data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb/)
and in details at [Google Rich snippets - Breadcrumbs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/185417)

`<ol> gives me style issues in Orchard CMS front end I use <ul> or use <div>` as in Google's, example.

Always close itemscope as itemscope="itemscope".

```
<ul>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
        <a href="#" itemprop="url">
            <span itemprop="title">Home</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="child" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
        <a href="#" itemprop="url">
            <span itemprop="title">Library</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="child" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
        <a href="#" itemprop="url">
            <span itemprop="title">Data</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```